# php mysql joining 4 tables with possible null values

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following sql which queries a database and pulls out the info from 4 different tables.

```
 SELECT d.item AS day, m.item as month, y.item as yr, l.item as local
 FROM date_day d
 JOIN date_month m ON d.recid=m.recid
 JOIN date_year y ON d.recid=y.recid
 JOIN location l ON d.recid=l.recid
 WHERE d.recid='cneta0ld00s6'
```

Its possible that one or more of those tables might empty and not contain a value. Particularly on the date fields. Will any of the above being empty or not existing, cause the whole thing to fail? Im particularly worried about date_day as I know mysql doesnt have a FUll JOIN.

Any thoughts?

Comment: is `location` the one table that will always have a record and then the `date` tables might be empty?

Comment: Unfortunately each one could be empty or missing. Its data on historic photos, so the day,month, year or location might not have been known by the person filling in the data. Im unfortunately stuck with a very poor database structure. Im wondering if its easier to do 4 seperate selects and load the results into an array!

Answer (score 1):

I think that:

```
SELECT d.item AS day, m.item as month, y.item as yr, l.item as local
 FROM date_day d
 LEFT JOIN date_month m ON d.recid=m.recid
 LEFT JOIN date_year y ON d.recid=y.recid
 LEFT JOIN location l ON d.recid=l.recid
 WHERE d.recid='cneta0ld00s6'
```

will do what you want it to

Comment: Im pretty sure though, that that expects the date_day table to include a column with the recid, like my single join does.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure I always got the data from the table even if its null, I added in a different table as the main table, one which will always include the recid, the table is photo. That way I ensure that the query will always return something even if its lots of nulls. THis meant I could use a left join too.

```
 SELECT p.photo_file, d.item AS day, m.item as month, y.item as yr, l.item as local
  FROM photo p
 LEFT JOIN date_day d ON p.recid=d.recid
 LEFT JOIN date_month m ON p.recid=m.recid
 LEFT JOIN date_year y ON p.recid=y.recid
 LEFT JOIN location l ON p.recid=l.recid
 WHERE p.recid='paul'
```